# How to know if your input is unique and doesn't have duplicates?

Tags: python-3.x

[image: Program]

The underlined sentences are what I'm having trouble adding in my code, I do know how to typecast numbers, but I don't know when in my code to do it.

```
gamblers = input().split()
winnings = 0
winnums =  ('10','11','8','1','5','20')
lim = len(gamblers)

for num in gamblers:
    if num in winnums:
        winnings+=100
if lim == 7:
    if winnings > 0:
        print(f"{gamblers[0]} won {winnings} pesos!")
    if winnings == 0:
        print (f"{gamblers[0]} won nothing!")
else:
    print("Should be 6 numbers")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert your inputs into a name and 6 numbers try:

```py
name = gamblers[0]
lotto_numbers = [int(x) for x in gamblers[1:]]
```

Note that this is a bit fragile in the sense that numbers that don't cast to `int` will throw an exception.

To test if you have 6 unique integers in that list you can:

```
duplicates_found = (len(lotto_numbers) != len(set(lotto_numbers)))
```

Casting to a `set()` will remove duplicates and hopefully after the cast we have the same number of numbers as we started with.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this answered my question and applied them to my code successfully.